# How to test ionic app on Ionic View

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-view

I'm using ionic app and try test on ionic view at this link:

```
https://dashboard.ionicframework.com/app
```

I have created a account and push my source from GIT to ionic view.. and then I have downloaded ionic view app to my mobile to test.. But seem it can not test my app although I have sign in with my account...

How to test my app on Ionic view ?